# Label individual plots in facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, facet-grid, geom-text

I am trying to finish this graph, and what I need is to add the R-squared to each graph individually.

However, the labels are superimposed on each graph.

I used `p + geom_text` and `p + geom_label` without positive results.

```
Trajectories$date<-as.POSIXct(Trajectories$date,"%Y-%m-%d",tz = "UTC")

# Reorder names in a new variable
Trajectories$variable_f = factor(Trajectories$variable, 
      levels=c("canopy_cover", "Leaf_litter", "Chla", "Shrimps", "macroinvertebrates"))

levels(Trajectories$variable_f) <- 
  c("textstyle('Canopy openness')", 
    "textstyle('Leaf litter')",
    "textstyle('Chlorophyll-')*italic('a')",
    "textstyle('Shrimps')",
    "atop(NA,atop(textstyle('Macroinvertebrate'),textstyle('density')))")

# Changes names in Facet_grid ---- es una manera buena, pero no la voy a usar --- Habria que labeller(variable_f = variable_f
#variable_f <- c("Canopy openness", "Leaf litter", "Chlorophyll-a","Shrimps","Macroinvertebrates")
#names(variable_f) <- c("canopy_cover", "Leaf_litter", "Chla", "Shrimps", "macroinvertebrates")

streams <- c("Prieta A", "Prieta B")
names(streams) <- c("QPA", "QPB")

# General graph -----------------------------------------------------------

 p<- ggplot(Trajectories, aes(date,value)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21, fill = "#bdd7e7", color = "#2171b5", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(se = T, size=1.7, color= "gray20", method = "gam", formula = y ~s(x)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color="gray20") +
  
  xlab('Year') + ylab("Change in magnitude") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, angle = 0)) + # axis x
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14, angle = 90)) + # axis 7
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=0, size=10, vjust=0.5, color="black")) + #subaxis x
  theme(axis.text.y=element_text(angle=0, size=10, vjust=0.5, color="black")) + #subaxis y
  
  ylim(-3,3) + 

  theme(legend.position="none")+
  
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray95"), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=0.5)) +
  
  facet_grid(vars(stream), vars(variable_f),
    labeller = labeller(variable_f = label_parsed, stream = streams)) +
    theme(
      strip.text.x = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
      strip.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = "black"),
      strip.placement = "outside") +
   theme(strip.background=element_rect(color= "black", fill="gray85")) +
   theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(0.001,0,0.001,0, "cm"))) +
    
 geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.POSIXct("2017-09-21")), # Hurricane Maria
            col= "red",linetype=4, alpha=0.9) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=as.POSIXct("2017-09-6")), # Hurricane Irma
             col= "blue",linetype=4, alpha=0.9) 
p
```

[image]

I tried to build a data frame with the labels. But it doesn't work, and it overlaps the labels.

```
labels <- data.frame(variable =c("canopy_cover","Leaf_litter","Chla","Shrimps","macroinvertebrates",
                                 "canopy_cover","Leaf_litter","Chla","Shrimps","macroinvertebrates"),
                     label=c("R1","R2","R3","R4","R5","R6","R7","R8","R9","R10"),
                     stream= c("QPA","QPA","QPA","QPA","QPA",
                               "QPB","QPB","QPB","QPB","QPB"))
labels
p +   geom_text(
  size    = 5,
  data    = labels,
  mapping = aes(x = as.POSIXct("2017-09-6"), y = Inf, label = label),
  hjust   = 1.05,
  vjust   = 1.5
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't provide the data, so I cannot experiment on myself. Nevertheless, for this graph  (this is not a general solution), changing the value of the date to e.g. "2019-09-06" in the call to `geom_text()` might do the trick. Please let me know whether this worked ;-)

Comment: This might be useful: https://github.com/eliocamp/tagger

Comment: @KoenV Thanks for the tip. But, don't use it. I made a new df and I was able to add each R to its respective plots. However, now the order of the plots has changed. Now the last plot is first.  I think the problem is to identify the name of the plots (their position in each column and row) to specify the R of each one.

Comment: @teunbrand Thanks, but what I need is not tags, it is to add a particular R to each plot.  Thanks again.